# Javascript framework for dealing with Anchors / AJAX-compatible bookmarks

Tags: javascript, ajax, bookmarks

Is there a framework around that supports dynamic (DHTML/AJAX/AHAH/JS/etc) page "permalinks" or bookmarks?

I'm looking for something that will support:

- Wiring frames/actions/code to page anchors
- Processing on-page clicks on anchor links
- Processing external clicks on anchor links (e.g. from a bookmark, on page load)

An example would be

```
http://mysite.com/user/something#favourites
```

Or as seen in an app like GMail, where each message or page has a permanent URL, as managed by the URL anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YUI browser history module does this, and the lite version may also do this.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/history/